# Erase repeated lines in r with a conditional column

Tags: r

I have this data: https://pastebin.com/x8HrT8qK

```
"sp";"mes";"ano";"code"
"56";"CM";7;2016;"CM52"
"57";"CM";2;2019;"CM52"
"58";"CM";11;2016;"CM53"
"59";"CM";9;2019;"CM53"
"60";"CM";5;2018;"CM53"
"61";"CM";5;2018;"CM53"
"374";"EI";8;2019;"EI26"
"375";"EI";8;2019;"EI26"
"376";"EI";3;2019;"EI26"
"377";"EI";7;2019;"EI26"
"378";"EI";11;2019;"EI26"
"379";"EI";2;2020;"EI26"
"380";"EI";10;2019;"EI27"
"381";"EI";11;2019;"EI27"
"382";"EI";11;2019;"EI27"
```

and I would like to exclude lines that have the same "code" only if they have the same "ano"

So that the data would look like this: https://pastebin.com/F7tkUZE1

```
"sp";"mes";"ano";"code"
"56";"CM";7;2016;"CM52"
"57";"CM";2;2019;"CM52"
"58";"CM";11;2016;"CM53"
"59";"CM";9;2019;"CM53"
"60";"CM";5;2018;"CM53"
"374";"EI";8;2019;"EI26"
"379";"EI";2;2020;"EI26"
"380";"EI";10;2019;"EI27"
```

Comment: Hello, could you post a code for what you've tried so far? The community takes questions better if there is at least an attempt, if not the community tend to think people are using the site for building code instead of needing help / learning.

Comment: try to improve your question, so that we can understand it a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I provide a non-base solution. `distinct` in `dplyr` can select unique rows from a data frame.

```
dplyr::distinct(df, ano, code, .keep_all = T)

#   sp mes  ano code
# 1 CM   7 2016 CM52
# 2 CM   2 2019 CM52
# 3 CM  11 2016 CM53
# 4 CM   9 2019 CM53
# 5 CM   5 2018 CM53
# 6 EI   8 2019 EI26
# 7 EI   2 2020 EI26
# 8 EI  10 2019 EI27
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `duplicated` to create a logical index of duplicate elements and then remove the rows based on the index.  Using `base R` (without any external packages)

```
df1[ !duplicated(df1[c('ano', 'code')]),]
#    sp mes  ano code
#56  CM   7 2016 CM52
#57  CM   2 2019 CM52
#58  CM  11 2016 CM53
#59  CM   9 2019 CM53
#60  CM   5 2018 CM53
#374 EI   8 2019 EI26
#379 EI   2 2020 EI26
#380 EI  10 2019 EI27
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv('file.csv', sep=";")   


df1 <- structure(list(sp = c("CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "CM", "EI", 
"EI", "EI", "EI", "EI", "EI", "EI", "EI", "EI"), mes = c(7L, 
2L, 11L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 2L, 10L, 11L, 11L), 
    ano = c(2016L, 2019L, 2016L, 2019L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 
    2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), 
    code = c("CM52", "CM52", "CM53", "CM53", "CM53", "CM53", 
    "EI26", "EI26", "EI26", "EI26", "EI26", "EI26", "EI27", "EI27", 
    "EI27")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", 
"380", "381", "382"))
```